# Check if any object in an array contains a property listed in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I've tried a few solutions to this and have had a look round on here but can't seem to get this working.

I have 2 arrays, and want to check if any of the items in the array contain any of the strings in the other array.

```
const stepsShown = ["ref2", "ref7"];
const items = [
{ name: "item1", element: "ref1"},
{ name: "item2", element: "ref2"}
];
const refsExist = items.some((r) =>{stepsShown.indexOf(r.element);});
```

In this example I would expect `refsExist` to be `true`

I think I am a little muddled in my syntax! Can anyone help please? :)

Comment: You want `includes`, not `indexOf` - and you need to return the result from the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it almost right, except that you need to test for a non `-1` value, and your arrow function shouldn't have brackets.

If your arrow function consists of a single expression, you don't need brackets:

```
items.some(r=>stepsShown.indexOf(r.element)!=-1);
```

If your arrow function includes statements or multiple expressions, you need curly brackets. When you use curly brackets, you must include an explicit `return` statement.

```
items.some(r=>{
    for(some;thing;) { ... }
    return otherThing;
});
```

Instead of relying on the less-readable `.indexOf(..)!=-1` test, you can simply use `includes`:

```
items.some(r=>stepsShown.includes(r.element));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find an element and later check if it is undefined or not

```js
const stepsShown = ["ref2", "ref7"];
const items = [
{ name: "item1", element: "ref1"},
{ name: "item2", element: "ref2"}
];
const refsExist = items.find((r) =>{    
    return stepsShown.indexOf(r.element)>-1;
});

console.log(refsExist !== undefined);
```